# LRUCache using stack is not efficient enough

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, lru

I am trying to solve the LeetCode problem [146. LRU Cache](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/):

> Design a data structure that follows the constraints of a [Least Recently Used (LRU) cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#LRU).
>
> Implement the LRUCache class:
>
> - `LRUCache(int capacity)` Initialize the LRU cache with **positive** size `capacity`.
> - `int get(int key)` Return the value of the `key` if the `key` exists, otherwise return -1.
> - `void put(int key, int value)` Update the value of the `key` if the `key` exists. Otherwise, add the `key-value` pair to the cache. If the number of keys exceeds the `capacity` from this operation, **evict** the least recently used key.
>
> The functions `get` and `put` must each run in O(1) average time complexity.

This is my code:

```java
class LRUCache {
    Stack<Integer> stack;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> cache;
    int capacity;
    
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        stack = new Stack<>();
        cache = new HashMap<>();        
    }
    
    public int get(int key) {
        if(!cache.containsKey(key)) return -1;
        else 
            stack.removeElement(key);
            stack.push(key);
            return cache.get(key);
    }
    
    public void put(int key, int value) {
        if(cache.containsKey(key)){
            stack.removeElement(key);
        }
        else if(stack.size() == capacity){
            int leastRecent = stack.remove(0);
            cache.remove(leastRecent);
        }
        stack.push(key);
        cache.put(key, value);
    }
}

/*
 * Your LRUCache object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * LRUCache obj = new LRUCache(capacity);
 * int param_1 = obj.get(key);
 * obj.put(key,value);
 */
```

All the test cases passed but I am getting "time limit exceeded" error:

[image: Error]

How can I improve the efficiency of my code?

Answer (score 0):

The time out occurs because `stack.removeElement(key)` does not have a good enough time complexity, and thus -- for some tests with bigger entry sets -- you'll get a time out.

The code challenge on LeetCode gives this information:

> The functions `get` and `put` must each run in O(1) average time complexity.

So that really means you cannot use `stack.removeElement` or anything that similarly has O() time complexity. It must be done more efficiently.

If you want to do this with your `HashMap` then you would need to have a doubly linked list, and then have the hashmap reference the node in that doubly linked list. That way you can remove a node in constant time.

But,... Java has all this done for you with [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)! The documentation explains:

> A special constructor is provided to create a linked hash map whose order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently (access-order). This kind of map is well-suited to building LRU caches.

So then the code becomes quite simple:

```
class LRUCache extends LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> {
    int capacity;  
    
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        // Foresee one more than desired capacity, so no extension is needed
        // when we allow a temporary overrun before deleting the eldest entry
        super(capacity + 1, 1, true); // true will enable the LRU behavior
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    // This method is called internally by put, getOrDefault (and similar).
    //    See documentation
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry) {
        return this.size() > this.capacity; // overrun detected: ask for removal
    }
    
    public int get(int key) {
        return getOrDefault(key, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: When asked in an interview setting, which is what LeetCode is for, this implementation makes little sense because it doesn't actually implement anything. Not to mention the solution is specific to Java, so, it has an unfair advantage for candidates who choose Java as the preferred language for the interview. As you've alluded to, an implementation using Doubly Linked Lists and a Hash Map works best here, and doesn't depend on any language-specific data structure.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, true, but the asker had targeted Java (it is even tagged with it), and had put no restrictions on its use. Best practice is to use the power of the language at hand. It also answers to the maximum "How can I improve its efficiency".

Comment: My point is that interviews impose artificial restrictions that a solution needs to honor. In real life, there are many battle-tested cache libraries in Java, and no one who’s not paid by LOC would venture to create one. Yet here we are.

Comment: Yes, these are artificial restrictions. But as LeetCode even imports the `java.util` library, making it available by default, they themselves invite the use of such native containers. You wrote it has an "unfair advantage", but LeetCode does not compare performance across languages. It provides performance statistics in comparison with other submissions that used the *same* language, so there is no cross-language competition., and no such unfairness.